# What is the use of @DeclareRoles in JakartaEE 8+ security?

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, authorization

In the past I always implemented authorization with some very proprietary code having an `@ApplicationScoped` bean with methods like `isUserInAnyOfTheseRoles(String... roles)`, which executes appropriate database queries. I always had to call these methods at the start of a protected EJB method/REST resource, making an if-statement and possibly throwing a "NotAuthorized"-exception.

For the future I consider using JakartaEE's security mechanisms so I am reading into it. I have a problem understanding the use of the `@javax.annotation.security.DeclareRoles` annotation.

Amongst others I read SO answer to [ejb Security questions regarding Roles and Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7219566). There it is said that

> The @DeclareRoles annotation on the other hand is merely used to declare a list of roles; [...]. The EJB container does not require knowledge of these roles to enforce access control checks on business methods of an EJB; instead, the bean provider/developer may use these roles in isCallerInRole tests to ensure programmatic security.

If I understand it right I need to declare the roles I use programmatically with `javax.security.enterprise.SecurityContext#isCallerInRole(String)`. So my class might look like the following.

```
@DeclareRoles({"ADD_ENTITY", "DELETE_ENTITY", "UPDATE_ENTITY", "SEE_ENTITY", "SEE_ENTITY_DETAILS", "SEE_RESTRICTED_DATA", "MERGE_ENTITY", "ATTACH_METADATA"})
public class PersonService {
    @Inject SecurityContext ctx;

    @RolesAllowed({"SEE_ENTITY"})
    public Person getPerson(long id) {
        if(ctx.isCallerInRole("SEE_ENTITY_DETAILS") {...}
        else if(ctx.isCallerInRole("SEE_RESTRICTED_DATA") {...}
        else {...}
    }
    ...
}
```

**1st question:**
Now if I have another class, do I need to declare all the roles again?

```
@DeclareRoles({"ADD_ENTITY", "DELETE_ENTITY", "UPDATE_ENTITY", "SEE_ENTITY", "SEE_ENTITY_DETAILS", "SEE_RESTRICTED_DATA", "MERGE_ENTITY", "ATTACH_METADATA"})
public class CompanyService {
    @Inject SecurityContext ctx;

    @RolesAllowed({"SEE_ENTITY"})
    public Company geCompany(long id) {
        if(ctx.isCallerInRole("SEE_ENTITY_DETAILS") {...}
        else {...}
    }
    ...
}
```

In the mentioned answer the EJB spec is quoted with

> The DeclareRoles annotation is specified on a bean class, where it serves to declare roles that may be tested by calling isCallerInRole [...]

**2nd question:** Is it correct that this declaration is *only* used by the programmatically access and not for the declarative part? So that I do not need to declare any roles if I only use the annotation `@RolesAllowed`.

**3rd question:** What is the reason for this "duplication"? For me it is just annoying to declare the roles (by the way I do have plenty of roles in my application) twice. I do not see the point in doing so, after all it is just a string. I need to write a custom `javax.security.enterprise.identitystore.IdentityStore` to map roles to a user. Aligning these roles in every EJB seems to be unnecessary.

**4th question:** In a comment to a similar question ([Define @DeclareRoles annotation programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55408591/5176800)) I interpret that @DeclareRoles might by a ancient relic and is no longer needed if an IdentityStore is used. If that would be true, it would make things a little bit clearer to me.

---

*Sorry for the four questions in one post, but it all tangled together somehow. Basically it is question 3 that haunts me the most.*